# ul wider than parent

Tags: html, css

I'm making a "menu" that will be able to slide. My question is how can I make the width of the ul fit the li's width even if it is wider than the with of the parent div.

I've made a simple example with html and css:

html:

```
<div class="parent">
  <ul class="child">
    <li>first</li>
    <li>second</li>
    <li>third</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

and the css:

```
.parent {width:50%;height:50px;background-color:#000;overflow:hidden}
ul {padding:0px;}
ul li {width:150px;background-color:#fff;display:inline-block;}
```

here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g1pbg5so/

thanks in advance.

Comment: sorry, are you wanting the li's to always be on one line - is that the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am understanding correctly, all you want to do is always have the li's on one line no matter the width of the div.

If this is the case then just add

```
.parent ul {
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

Updated snippet:

```css
.parent {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #000;
  overflow: hidden
}
ul {
  padding: 0px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
ul li {
  width: 150px;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <ul class="child">
    <li>first</li>
    <li>second</li>
    <li>third</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to force all list items on the same line, and make them scroll in their parent:

```
.parent {width:400px;height:50px;background-color:#000;overflow:scroll}
ul {float:left;padding:0px; whitespace: nowrap; }
```

Change the overflow to 'scroll' and force the ul's wrapping on 'nowrap'

Demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/g1pbg5so/2/